# I am trying to build an LWC for a Checkbox Button Group which changes the text of the button based on the checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to make a re-usable LWC for checkbox button groups. I built an LWC and used the @api decorator to expose an array for passing in objects to use as the individual checkbox buttons.

However, I want to change the label of the button when it is checked. To do this I want to change the value of the appropriate option that is being used to render the checkbox buttons. But for some reason I cannot change the value of the element in the array that is passed into the component.

I've tried a few things based on what I've read here, but nothing seems to work.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">{label}</legend>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-checkbox_button-group">
                <span class="slds-button slds-checkbox_button" 
                    if:true={options} 
                    for:each={options} 
                    for:item="option"
                    key={option.id} >
                    <input type="checkbox" id={option.label.on} data-option-id={option.id} value={option.value} name={option.label.on} onchange={handleToggleChange} checked={option.value}/>
                    <label class="slds-checkbox_button__label" for={option.label.on}>
                        <span if:true={option.value} class="slds-checkbox_faux">{option.label.on}</span>
                        <span if:false={option.value} class="slds-checkbox_faux">{option.label.off}</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class CheckboxButtonGroup extends LightningElement {
    @api options=[];
    @api label='';

    handleToggleChange(event){
        let i = parseInt(event.target.dataset.optionId);
        this.options[i].value=event.target.checked;
        this.options = [...this.options];
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail:{label:event.target.name,checked:event.target.checked }}));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@api` variables are read-only. This restriction enforces the one-way data transfer model that LWC uses to avoid various glitches found in Aura's two-way binding model. To fix this, either have the parent fix the new value, or use a backing variable. Here's an example of the latter:

```
@api set options(value) {
  this._options = [...value.map(option=>({...option}))];
};
get options() {
  return this._options;
}
_options;
@api label='';


handleToggleChange(event){
    let i = parseInt(event.target.dataset.id);
    debugger;
    const opt = this._options.find(option=>option.id===i);
    opt.value = event.target.checked;
    this._options = [...this._options];
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail:{label:event.target.name,checked:event.target.checked }}));
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/zAwdJUA1APDuXy4xeVsT/src/child.js?p=stories).